# IIS WordPress site on alternative port and rewrite rules

Tags: iis, rewrite, port, wordpress, asp.net-mvc

I had 2 websites running on a server with 2 different hostnames. Lets call them

> 1 - hostname1.host.com
>
> 2 - hostname2.host.com

`hostname1.host.com` was bound to a WordPress site and `hostname2.host.com` was bound to a ASP.NET MVC site. Additionally, there were 2 more MVC sites that served as QA and staging on ports `8000` and `8008` respectively. These could naturally have been accessed through either hostname or simply on the server's IP address.

As of yesterday, the WordPress site is obsolete. I've bound the `hostname1.host.com` to the MVC site as this is the one I want to use and removed this hostname from the WordPress site's binding.

I have 2 global URL rewrite rules:

[image]

The first rule redirects all traffic with the server's ip address to `hostname1.host.com` except for ports `8000`, `8080` and `8008`.

The second rule redirects all traffic on `hostname2.host.com` to `hostname1.host.com`. I've also included the ports from this rule.

Then, on the live MVC site I also have a rule that redirects all port `80` traffic to `443`:

[image]

The problem I'm having is wanting to bind the WordPress site to port `8080` which is not working. I have:

[image]

On my live site I have bindings (just imagine under the red it says hostname1.host.com):

[image]

What then happens when I try to access the WordPress site on any of the domains or the ip address on port `8080` is I get the redirect:

`<h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://hostname1.host.com/">here</a>`

This should not be happening. There should be no rule that redirects port `8080` to the hostname.

I can still access the staging and qa site's just fine. I've even tried swapping the QA site's port with the WordPress site's port. Then I can access the QA site on port `8080`, but port `8000` redirects to the hostname.

---

From IIS logs:

There is a lot of this:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-11-24 12:27:57
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-11-24 12:27:57 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.87.250 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1687
2016-11-24 12:36:09 192.168.3.7 GET /Default/ChurchGroups - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1119
2016-11-24 12:36:17 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1157
2016-11-24 12:36:23 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1171
2016-11-24 12:36:35 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1156
2016-11-24 12:36:43 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1171
2016-11-24 12:37:06 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1147
2016-11-24 12:37:20 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1156
2016-11-24 12:37:32 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1140
2016-11-24 12:37:39 192.168.3.7 GET / - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1171
2016-11-24 12:38:11 192.168.3.7 GET /Default/Schools - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1187
2016-11-24 12:38:25 192.168.3.7 GET /Default/Schools - 8080 - 169.1.134.14 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/54.0.2840.99+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 1185
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the IIS logs for when this happens? It sounds like there is a catch all in place somewhere and the IIS logs may contain more info depending on the logging level.

Comment: I've posted some lines from the logs. I don't see anything that would indicated redirection.